# Gnuplot replot command doesn't build a plot

Tags: gnuplot

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
reset
NO_ANIMATION = 1

set terminal png size 1920, 1080
set output 'graph1.png'
set size 1, 1

set key left box

set title "Кусочно-линейный график"
set xlabel "Количество элементов, шт"   
set ylabel "Время, мкс"

set grid
plot './preproc/average_O0_A0_S0.txt' with linespoints title 'O0 a[i]' lc "red"
replot './preproc/average_O0_A1_S0.txt' with linespoints title 'O0 *(a + n)' lc "blue"
replot './preproc/average_O0_A2_S0.txt' with linespoints title "O0 *p" lc "green"
replot './preproc/average_O2_A0_S0.txt' with linespoints title "O2 a[i]" lc "yellow"
replot './preproc/average_O2_A1_S0.txt' with linespoints title "O2 *(a + n)" lc "black"
replot './preproc/average_O2_A2_S0.txt' with linespoints title "O2 *p" lc "purple"
```

I use this Gnuplot code to build 6 plots in one png image. But the replot commands don't work. Only the first plot is built. [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHPWL.png) is attached (press the button). All used files exist and have the same structure as the first one. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you talking about 6 graphs in 6 coordinate systems or 6 lines in 1 coordinate system? Or the latter in other words: should these line graphs share the same x- and y-axes?

Comment: I need 6 lines in one coordinate system, they should share the same axes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A png file can only contain one image.  That is a limitation of the PNG format.  Also - I think the "replot" command is not what you want in any case.  Please expand your question to decribe what the result should look like.

**edit**

> I need 6 lines in one coordinate system, they should share the same axes

In that case you want only a single plot command with the individual components separated by commas (see response from theozh).

Comment: I need 6 lines in one coordinate system, they should share the same axes.

Answer (score 0):

From where did you get that `replot` command?

If you need 6 lines in one coordinate system, you simple add the plot elements separated with  `,` check `help plot`:

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>  plot {<ranges>} <plot-element> {, <plot-element>, <plot-element>}
> ```

And here additionally `\` for continuing the line (better readability).
Check PDF manual "Introduction":

> Commands may extend over several input lines by ending each line but the last with a backslash (`\`). The
> backslash must be the last character on each line. The effect is as if the backslash and newline were not there.

```
plot './preproc/average_O0_A0_S0.txt' w lp title 'O0 a[i]' lc "red", \
     './preproc/average_O0_A1_S0.txt' w lp title 'O0 *(a + n)' lc "blue", \
     './preproc/average_O0_A2_S0.txt' w lp title "O0 *p" lc "green", \
     './preproc/average_O2_A0_S0.txt' w lp title "O2 a[i]" lc "yellow", \
     './preproc/average_O2_A1_S0.txt' w lp title "O2 *(a + n)" lc "black", \
     './preproc/average_O2_A2_S0.txt' w lp title "O2 *p" lc "purple"
```